# javascript keeping count on how many times a picture is deleted

Tags: javascript

I never used javascript in this way, but I would like to keep track of how many times a delete button is pressed. When the page originally loads I want to set the "value" to 0 and as they press delete keep track. Here is what I have is what obviously does not work, I didnt want to go the route of making a hidden variable and keep track that way. Thanks for any help.

Script

```
var deletePictureCount;
function MenuAction() {

}
MenuAction.prototype = {
    GetDeletePictureCount: function () {
        if (deletePictureCount == null || deletePictureCount < 0) { return 0; }
        return deletePictureCount;
    },
    SetDeletePictureCount: function () {
        deletePictureCount++;
    }
};
```

usage on delete

```
 var incement = new MenuAction().SetDeletePictureCount();
```

usage when trying to get value back

```
 var deletedPiccount = new MenuAction().GetDeletePictureCount();
```

Comment: This is all pretty wacky looking honestly. Certainly you should at least initialize the global `deletePictureCount` var to `0`. Otherwise, how can `deletePictureCount++` make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your script:

`var deletePictureCount;` - Better set it's initial value if you gon'na use "set" before "get" before ;

`if (deletePictureCount == null || deletePictureCount < 0) { return 0; }` - this term is needless: I didn't see how exactly your `deletePictureCount` can get a negative value through your script.

Use `if( deletePictureCount ) return deletePictureCount;` instead.

It should look like

```
var deletePictureCount = 0;
function MenuAction() {

}
MenuAction.prototype = {
    GetDeletePictureCount: function () {
        if ( deletePictureCount ) return deletePictureCount; //if deletePictureCount is not null or 0 - return it's value;
        return 0; // else return 0;
    },
    SetDeletePictureCount: function () {
        deletePictureCount++;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks a little odd to me - you aren't setting an initial value to the variable, and you are creating two instances of an object to get/set the value? And you are setting a return value to `increment` but aren't returning a value in that function.

Why not just use `deletePictureCount++` and be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `deletePictureCount` to `0` like here,

http://jsbin.com/axeyiq/2/edit#javascript,html